# retrieving data from two mysql tables where the second table depends on the first

Tags: mysql, multiple-tables

I have two MySql tables:

```
 users(id_user, name, age, gender ).

 ways(#id_user,id_way,  start, end, date).
```

What I want is to retrieve all the ways with their corresponding  users details. 
So my result would be like this:

```
 id_way  | start  | end    | date       | id_user  | name  | age   | gender
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2       | place1 | place2 | 12/06/2013 | 145      | john  | 28    | m
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html)?

```
SELECT ways.id_way, ways.start, ways.end, ways.date, users.* 
FROM ways JOIN users USING (id_user)
```

Comment: can i do more than a single JOIN ?  i mean can i edit the query so i can retrieve from table preferences(id_pref, #id_user, value) so the result would be retrieving each way with its corresponding user including their preferences.

Comment: You can certainly have multiple JOINs.  In this case, since it may be possible for user to have no preferences, you would need to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN rather than the standard (INNER) JOIN.  You may also need to pivot the data if you want all of a user's preferences to be returned in a single row. Open another question if you need help with this.

Comment: yes, thanks @PinnyM , things are more clear now. i actually want to join the 3 tables to do manipulate the data easily on my web site using JSON objects.